# how do I make a variable string, instead of an integer?

Tags: python, variables, integer, typeerror

I keep getting a TypeError saying I need a string, not and integer.
this is what I have tried.

```
cash_1 = int{cash_1} + 1
```

this is the code line it is saying the TypeError is on.

```
cash_1 += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a function - you need to call it with regular parentheses, not curly braces:

```py
cash_1 = int(cash_1) + 1
# Here -----^------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong punctuation; you want parentheses `()` to call functions such as `int`, not `{}` (which are used e.g. for sets and dictionaries).

```
cash_1 = int(cash_1) + 1
```